# ASP.net html table export to excel

Tags: asp.net, html-table, export-to-excel

I use this way to export excel, but there's no data show up. How to fix it? Or, is there any other way to export?

```
protected void exportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
   Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";                                                      
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename = ExcelFile.xls");
   Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;                                                                     
   StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();                                                                   
   HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
   table.RenderControl(hw);
   Response.Write(tw.ToString());                                                                   
   Response.End();
 }
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'WebService.asmx/GetFees',
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                            var html_data1 = '<td data-name="electricity_fee" class="electricity_fee" data-type="text" data-pk="' + data[count].YM + '">' + data[count].electricity_fee + '</td>';
                            var html_data2 = '<td data-name="material_fee" class="material_fee" data-type="text" data-pk="' + data[count].YM + '">' + data[count].material_fee + '</td>';
      
                            $('#electricity_fee').append(html_data1);
                            $('#material_fee').append(html_data2);

                        };
                        
                    };
                });    
       
    </script>
```

```html
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExport" Text="Export EXCEL" OnClick="exportExcel_Click" CssClass="btn btn-danger" /> 

    <table  class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="table" runat="server" border="1">
       <thead>
        <tr><th class="table-title" colspan="13" style="text-align:center">Spending</th></tr>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:15%">Month</th>
            <th>2018/1</th>
            <th>2018/2</th>
            <th>2018/3</th>
            <th>2018/4</th>
            <th>2018/5</th>
            <th>2018/6</th>
            <th>2018/7</th>
            <th>2018/8</th>
            <th>2018/9</th>
            <th>2018/10</th>
            <th>2018/11</th>
            <th>2018/12</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody id="data">
           <tr id="electricity_fee"><td>electricity_fee</td></tr>
           <tr id="material_fee">material_fee<td></td></tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: FYI: Excel files are *not* text or html files.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for answering. The last I used table2excel.js to export.